# Modify product labels xml in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I’m having several issues when trying to modify the default template of product labels. I need to add some new fields to the existing template that generates the document of product labels (and to design in with proper dimensions).

I am not able to find the xml template to modify it because I can’t find the file. This is a topic I have been researching deeply through the internet during the lasts days and all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

On the Internet, it is said that the product labels are generated using the product/report/product-label.xml and product_label.xsl:
https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/product-label-prints-only-one-variant-attribute-74684

The issue is that I can’t files these files in my Odoo installation folder (tested with both Windows and Ubuntu). These are my folder contents in Ubuntu usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/product/report:
[image]

Should I create the xml and xsl files?

If so, how can I reference them? I have already tried to modify the xml file to try if the options for rendering the report change and nothing’s happens...

Here is the xml that I have been modifying (looks like it is an index of the different available reports but I haven’t found any official documentation regarding this) (note that I’ve added a number to each report title to see if something changes):

[image]

And the select options are still the same, as it can be seen in the following screenshot. 
[image]

Am I’m missing something? It looks like these templates are located somewhere else and I’m editing these files without success (and restarting the Odoo server doesn’t work either...).

I'm using Odoo v12.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<report>` tag in odoo is actually shortcut of `ir.action.report` model record creation, `qweb-pdf or qweb-html` type of report needs a qweb template to render the report output, which is mentioned in `name` and `file` properties in the `report` tag.

After changing the files in a odoo module, if that module is already installed before change, you have to update the module. You can update from `Apps` menu of odoo web panel. For example, in this case, you are making change in `product` module which is named `Products & Pricelists` in odoo Apps. After making change, update that module and you will find the changes effective. Also, if you are adding new `XML` file, you have to add respective file name in `__manifest.py__`, or have to import in `__init.py__` if you are adding new python file in the module.

Comment: Superb answer. Really helpful! Thank you!